# PostgreSQL: Reuse function code that works on virtual table data

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, code-reuse, postgresql-9.4

I have code that works on a dataset (= multiple rows) of 3 cols (`id | timestamp | value`) and produces a single numerical result (the *score*).

Now I want to put this code in a function so that I can reuse it. Let's say I have 4 other queries that all produce a dataset with these 3 cols and I want to calculate the *score* from that, without having to copy/paste my code... How can I do that? It seems passing a `TABLE(...)` type as a function parameter is not possible.

I think I can't use an aggregate function, because my scoring code internally adds new rows, groups them and so on. I need to work on all rows at once and have no state transition.

Comment: What's a "virtual table"? You mean a table function ("set-returning function")? Please show your function code (or a simplified example) and elaborate on `want to reuse my scoring code`. You need to be more specific what you want to do exactly. Postgres has no table variables, there are other ways ...

Comment: What I wanted to say is that I have code that works on a dataset of 3 cols (```id | timestamp | value``` - there is no table or anything) and produces a single numerical result (the score). But now I want to put this code in a function so that I can reuse it. Let's say I have 4 other queries that all produce a dataset with these 3 cols and now I want to calculate the score from that without having to paste my code... I think I can't create an aggregate function, because my scoring code internally adds new rows, groups them and so on. I need to work on all rows at once.

Comment: Please *edit the question* instead of putting much essential information into comments. That's not the place.

Comment: I rewrote the question.

Comment: You could create a custom type with those three columns, then your queries could pass an instance of that type, something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4245b/1

Comment: My problem is that my function needs to work on a dataset ( = multiple rows). I edited by question to make that more clear.

Comment: then please show us the code of your function

Comment: As the question says, there is no function yet. For example: imagine some query that sorts the rows by ```id``` first, then multiplies the very first row.value with the value of 4th, and sets that as new value of the first row. then it returns the first value that is <5 as a *score*. Something like that.

Comment: So which code are you referring to when you say "*I **have** code that works on a dataset*" Where is that code? What is it doing right now?

Comment: I can't copy you that. It's like the code/query I just described as an example. It is working on multiple rows and produces one single value -> the score. I'm just searching a general way/pattern that helps me reusing code like this. I don't know how to make it clearer than that.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show the code you want to reuse with dynamic input. If your function is too complex, provide a simplified example to showcase the essential principal. Sounds like you are going to need [dynamic SQL](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `because my scoring code internally adds new rows, groups them and so on.` Do you mean that after the (scalar) function is finished, the database state is different? Does the function *change* the database?

Comment: No, just in memory for calculation. I wanted to picture that I need to work on all the collected rows at once to calculate the result. Can't just have a value that is updated on each state transition.

Answer (score 2):

The question is very interesting because it leads to reflection on the non-standard use of custom aggregate functions.

> (...) imagine some query that sorts the rows by id first, then multiplies
>   the very first row.value with the value of 4th,  and sets that as new
>   value of the first row. then it returns the first value that is <5 as
>   a score.

We need:

- a custom composite type as an aggregate operates on the values of a particular type,
- a state transition function, which saves consecutive rows in a temporary table,
- a final function, which performs calculations and returns final result.

---

```
create type scores as (id int, val numeric);

create function save_scores(p scores, n scores)
returns scores language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if p is null then 
        create temp table temp_scores of scores;
    end if;
    insert into temp_scores values (n.id, n.val);
    return n;
end $$;

create function calculate_scores(t scores)
returns numeric language plpgsql as $$
declare
    id1 int;
    val4 numeric;
    res numeric;
begin
    select id into id1 from temp_scores order by id limit 1;
    select val into val4 from temp_scores order by id offset 3 limit 1;
    update temp_scores set val = val* val4 where id = id1;
    select val into res from temp_scores where val < 5 order by id limit 1;
    drop table temp_scores;
    return res;
end $$;
```

The aggregate:

```
create aggregate get_scores(scores) (
    sfunc = save_scores,
    finalfunc = calculate_scores,
    stype = scores
);
```

and some checks:

```
select get_scores(row)
from (
    values (4, 3.1), (3, 1.2), (2, 5.2), (1, 2)
    ) row
-- gives 1.2

select get_scores(row)
from (
    values (4, 3.1), (3, 1.2), (2, 5.2), (1, 1)
    ) row
-- gives 3.1
```

The aggregate can be used only once in a single query due to the use of temporary table. Column `timestamp` omitted for simplicity.

Comment: My problem is that my function needs to work on a dataset of multiple rows. I edited by question to make that more clear.

Comment: With a simple function it is not possible. You have to create an aggregate.

Comment: Wow! I did read it. What you have written about the aggregate function is not true. This is the only solution and not that difficult. Of course, if I understand correctly what is your goal.

Comment: Sorry, but you just wrote "create an aggregate" without any further comment. That sounded as if you hadn't read the question. ;) Thank you for the answer - interesting. What I don't understand are the performance implications of a temporary table. I might be doing >100 requests a second - I think temp tables will still write to disc?

Comment: it is ok. Temporary tables are handled in the memory (unless an overflow occurs). However, this solution does not appear to be especially efficient.